# OpenCv Linking Issue

Tags: opencv, linker

I'm using Kubuntu and have some Problems with linking OpenCv ( 2.4.6.1 ) Librarys ( I guess ).

So I've been using this tutorial http://karytech.blogspot.de/2012/05/opencv-24-on-ubuntu-1204.html and got the installation tested ok ( section: ./opencv_test_core ). Then I downloaded the testfile below but could make it work. Tried some other code always the same error:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -lcv -lcxcore -lcvaux -lhighui -lm hello.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcxcore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcvaux
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighui
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück ( ld exit status is 1 )
```

( as for the strange library names in the tutorial i also tried -lopencv_calib3d ... )

then tried it in code::blocks and get this:

main.c   undefined reference to cvGetRows

Headers are in /usr/local/include/opencv
               /usr/local/include/opencv2
Librarys are in usr/local/lib

( If that helps ):

```
$ pkg-config --cflags opencv
returns: -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include  

$ pkg-config --libs opencv
returns: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so ...

$ apt-cache search opencv
returns: opencv-doc - OpenCV documentation and examples
python-opencv - Python-Anbindungen für die OpenCV-Bibliothek
libavcodec-extra-53 - Libav codec library ...
```

Comment: honestly, this all looks horribly out of date. -lcv -lcxcore -lcvaux -lhighui were the opencv1.0 libs. that's more than 6 years ago

Comment: also, opencv comes with its own python wrappers (cv2) since 5 years already. you won't need python-opencv at all, better avoid it even

Comment: yeah most propobly, was also wondering on the strange names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To link against `OpenCV`, you have to pass `g++` (which will run `ld` internally) where the libraries are (if they are not standard ones). You can do it manually, if you want to link only some of them.
But the fastest way is to rely on `pkg-config`:

```
g++ faceDetect.cpp $(pkg-config --libs opencv --cflags)
```

However, in the package there's a `Makefile`, just `cd` the directory you've extracted that archive, and run `make`.

Comment: As for faceDetect i could compile it but got another problem and when i compile only a main with just a cvWaitKey(0) i now get this:

Comment: OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvWaitKey, file /home/daniel/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 562
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/daniel/Downloads/opencv-2.4.7/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:562: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+...

Comment: @user3340703 , that's sad, but true. it means, your highgui module was compiled without any gui. you need to get either qt or gtk2 and  recompile the opencv libs (cmake)

Comment: I'm not an Ubuntu machine, but `# apt-get install libopencv-dev` should install a precompiled version with all the dependencies needed. Unless you explicitly need/want your own compiled one.

Comment: well, i added to cmake: -D WITH_QT=ON is there something else i should have done?

Comment: Yes, it should be enough. Check [this](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/op/opencv-qt/PKGBUILD) out for more options.

Comment: Ok, now Ive done: 1. cmake without the -D WITH_QT=ON option and 1000% installed libgtk2.0-dev 2. make 3. make install 4. tried programms again with same error

Comment: Keep us updated and mark the question as solved when you have done.

Comment: You should run `make install` as root.